# Find the top-most NSView object located under NSPoint position

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode7, osx-elcapitan

*I know this question was already asked here in few forms but unfortunately non of the suggested solutions worked for me.*
I am implementing a *multi-touch* capability for my `osx` app.
***My problem:***
I need to resolve a location on the screen, described by `NSPoint` in screen coordinates, to the very top `NSView` object **from my application** that resides under this location (if any).
This is a bit like `HWND WindowFromPoint( Point)` under `Windows` OS.

*Few points to consider:*

- My application manage several `NSWindow`s, where each window contains an hierarchy of several `NSView`s,
- The `NSView` that I am interested in is not necessarily the application `Key Window` or `Main Window`, as it can be any of my other currently non-active `NSView` objects that happen to be under this screen location,
- It is possible that under a particular `NSPoint` I will have more then one `NSWindow`s and/or `NSView`s. In this case I wll be interested only in the very top-most `NSView`,
- It is possible that `NSView` A is on top of `NSView` B, partialy hiding it, but the `NSPoint` location is present only on B, which is not the very top-most window of the application (but only the very top-most for this location). Here again I will be interested in B.

*Things that I managed todo:*

- Enumerate `NSApp` for all its windows (`NSApp.windows`),
- Enumerate `NSWindow` for its views (`NSWindow.contentView.subviews`),
- Enumerate `NSView` for its sub-views (`NSView.subviews`)

Doing this I managed to enumerate all `NSView`s of my application, but I still need to filter out non-relevant `NSView`s, which are not visible.

*Things that **did not** work for me:*

- `NSView.hitTest` returned `nil` for valid locations,
- `NSView.layer.zPosition` alwyas is zero (0),
- The order of the `NSView.subviews` list also does not reflacts the current GUI layout,
- Testing if `NSView` is Visible also did not help as it returns true also if this window is hidden by other window.

My environment:
`Mac`, `OSX El-Capitan`, `XCode-7`, `Cocoa`, `Objective-C`

Thanks for any help!
PazO

Comment: To which view do you send `hitTest`?

Comment: To each `NSView` enumerated. i.e. - all `NSView` objects in my application afaik. All will return `nil`...

Comment: Calling `hitTest:` of `window.contentView` should be enough. Do you convert the point to window coordinates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
// 1. Get the Window-Number of the NSWindow object owning this point:
NSInteger   wndNumber   = [NSWindow windowNumberAtPoint:(point) belowWindowWithWindowNumber:(0)];
// 2. Get the NSWindow object associated with this particular Window-Number:
NSWindow*   window      = [NSApp windowWithWindowNumber:(wndNumber)];
// 3. Convert NSPoint values from System-coordinates to NSWindow-coordinates (Thanks @Willeke for his comment)
NSRect      rctScreen;
    rctScreen.origin        = point;
    rctScreen.size.height   = rctScreen.size.width = 0;
NSRect      rctWindow   = [window convertRectFromScreen:rctScreen];
// 4. Now do the hitTest:
NSView*     viewFound   = [[window contentView] hitTest:rctWindow.origin];
```

Obviously each line should be tested for `nil`, but I leave this out for code brevity.